# This document "XXXXX.storyboard" could not be opened. Please use a newer version of Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios5, storyboard, ios6, xcode-storyboard

Storyboards created with `XCode 4.5.1` could not open on `XCode 4.2` with the following error message.

`This document "XXXXX.storyboard" could not be opened. Please use a newer version of Xcode. Consider changing the document's Development Target to preserve compatibility.`

Changed the Deployment target to `iOS 5.0` under `Document Versioning` (as suggested by google results) but without any success.

Any fix for this ?

Comment: "Please use a newer version of Xcode." is what is told you, I think you should really consider that.

Comment: aaah, that'll require us to upgrade from snow-leopard as well. Thanks for the suggestion. Will wait and see if there's a fix.

Comment: Ah, so you would need to upgrade the whole OS? :( You should have started with this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the storyboard's development target to Xcode 4.2. The menu to set the development target is in the Document Versioning section.

Answer (score 48):

I have given +1 to `@MarkSzymczyk` as it pointed me in the right direction, but as it is a little bit old compared to the new `xcode 5` I thought I would give an up-to-date answer.

I came across this issue where I was getting

> > This document "XXXXX.storyboard" could not be opened. Please use a newer version of Xcode. Consider changing the document's Development Target to preserve compatibility.

when I had looked at my project in `xcode 5` and went back to `xcode 4.6`. The way to solve this is slightly different from the old `xcode`. I had to load the project back up in `xcode 5` and navigate to the storyboard in the interface builder. In there there is now an "Interface Builder Document" section instead of the "Document Versioning" section. Under there, there is an option to change what version of `xcode` you would like to open in. All you need to do is change back to `xcode 4.x`.

I don't want to take away from the other answer as it is correct still I just want to expand on that answer.

Comment: good find. I had the same issue but with a regular .xib file (not storyboard) and this fix works for that as well.

Comment: Note that selecting XCode 4.X will give you a warning that you would lose the ability to edit the iOS 7 appearance

Comment: @BlackTigerX Yes, but at the time of writing this I was on xcode 5 preview 2 I think and that warning didn't appear.